# Sum of random numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to write a program that creates and sums 50 random numbers [1,3]. With my current code, I have an out put of 50 numbers side by side, but I can figure out how to add them. I tried `int sum = sim + i;` but that only doubled the number of digits created. I'm using Eclipse and appreciate any assistance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50;
        runSimulation(n);

    }
    public static void runSimulation (int n){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            int sim = (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
            System.out.print(sim);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't all `int` should be `long`?? Math.random()* **2.9999**

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @FahimParkar What do you mean? I don't think that he needs a long type at all, as the numbers fall within the integer range.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50;
        int sum = runSimulation(n);
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
    public static int runSimulation (int n){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            int sim = (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
            sum += sim;
            System.out.print(sim + " ");
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I totally forgot about return statements, thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this...

```
     int total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++){
               int sim = (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
               System.out.print(sim+" ");
               total = total+sim;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Output](http://ideone.com/apUFv) [image]

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is `int sim = (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;`.

You should initialise sim before the cycle `double sim = 0;` and use `sim = sim + (int)(Math.random()*2.9999);`

But better to use `sim += (int)(Math.random() * 3.);`

Answer (score 1):

```
int sim = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  sim += (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
}
System.out.print(sim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an `int` variable that holds the running total and set it to `0`.

Inside of the loop, add to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise sim outside of your for loop you're using to sum.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting sum during each iteration of the loop.

Pull the declaration of the variable and the print statement out of the loop, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 50;
        runSimulation(n);

    }
    public static void runSimulation (int n){
        int sim = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            sim += (int)(Math.random()*2.9999) + 1;
        }
        System.out.print(sim);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to initialise the local variable `sim` and it's still not summing up the randoms

Comment: Oops! A little bit tired over here. Thank you. I could have sworn that I initialized it and used `+=`, but apparently I was falling asleep at the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

Two main suggestions:

- Keep a running total in a "sum" variable that you add to in each loop iteration.
- Use [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) rather than Math.random() (since you want integer values)

So the code might then look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    runSimulation(50);
}

public static void runSimulation(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    java.util.Random rand=new java.util.Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int sim = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        sum = sum + sim;
        System.out.print(sim);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total = "+sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 50;
    runSimulation(count);
}

private static void runSimulation(int count) {
    int sum = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
        System.out.print(number);
        sum += number;
    }
    System.out.println("\nSum: " + sum);
}
```